# DOTween use Append(Tween) instead AppendCallback(()=> foo())

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

How can I use Append(Tween) instead AppendCallback(()=> foo()) on Sequence.
It will be useful to start some animation and return Tween with duration equals clip.duration

At the moment I can transfer duration of clip and use some public void to start animation:

```
_sequence
    .AppendCallback(some.Foo)
    .AppendInterval(some.FooDuration)
```

And I have to definite this:

```
class Some
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
    [SerializeField] private AnimationClip _fooClip;
    
    public float FooDuration => _fooClip.length;

    public void Foo()
    {
        _animator.Play(_fooClip.name);
    }
}
```

I'm sure it can be better. Something like that:

```
_sequence
    .Append(some.Foo())
```

And it should be defined as like this:

```
class Some
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
    [SerializeField] private AnimationClip _fooClip;
    
    private float _fooDuration => _fooClip.length;

    public Tween Foo()
    {
        _animator.Play(_fooClip.name);
        return DOTween.To(() => 0, (x) => x = 0, 0, _fooDuration); //Not this sheeet
    }
}
```

UPD: Sorry, I missed the brackets.
But question is What I can return from Tween Foo() ?
Not DOTween.To(() => 0, (x) => x = 0, 0, _fooDuration) but maybe some empty Tween with specific duration

Answer (score 0):

**Append** requires a tween instead of a method.

```
_sequence
    .Append(some.Foo())
```

Comment: Thanks!  I missed the brackets, but it is not my question. 
question is What I can return from Tween Foo() ? Not DOTween.To(() => 0, (x) => x = 0, 0, _fooDuration) but maybe some empty Tween with specific duration

Comment: What's wrong with DOTween.To? It's an empty tween with a duration, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I think it is not right to calculate nothing every time while you want just wait some time on Tween. 
And you'll not want to write on every method/tween return DOTween.To(() => 0, (x) => x = 0, 0, _fooDuration)

Comment: You're right, it feels unnecessary, but it's only a single float. I actually use these calls all over the place in my game and the performance is fine.